# How do I get EditContext to register a change to a List?

Tags: .net, blazor

I have a Form with an EditContext in Blazor.

As part of the form I have a `List` of `Products` where I can add and remove products.
As part of the `List`, each product has a `Qty` count. When I update the `Qty` in the `Product`, `EditContext` gets notified of an update. But when I add/remove a `Product` from the `List`, it doesn't get notified.

Any idea how I can get my `EditContext` to detect this?

```
<EditForm EditContext="FormEditContext" method="post" OnValidSubmit="SaveForm">
    <MatTable Context="formProduct" Items="formModel.Items" ShowPaging="false">
    <MatTableHeader>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </MatTableHeader>
    <MatTableRow>
        <td>
            <MatSelectItem 
                Context="product"
                @bind-Value="@formProduct.TariffProduct"
                TValue="Product"
                Items="AvailableProducts.ToList()">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    @product.Name
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </MatSelectItem>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><MatNumericUpDownField TValue="int" @bind-Value="formProduct.Quantity" Minimum="1" FullWidth="true"></MatNumericUpDownField></p>
        </td>
        <td>@string.Format("£{0:f2}", formProduct.Amount)</td>
        <td><MatButton Type="button" Class="btn btn-danger" OnClick="() => RemoveProduct(formProduct)" Disabled="!CanEdit">Remove</MatButton></td>
    </MatTableRow>
</MatTable>
<MatButton Type="button" OnClick="AddProduct"">+ Add Product</MatButton>
</EditForm>
```

```
public void AddProduct()
{
    formModel.Items.Add(new FormProduct()
    {
        Id = AvailableProducts.FirstOrDefault().Id,
        Product = AvailableProducts.FirstOrDefault(),
        Quantity = 1,
    });
}

public void RemoveProduct(
    FormProduct formProduct)
{
    formModel.Items.Remove(formProduct);
}
```

Above is an example

Comment: Use this.StateHasChanged();

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but that didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer

```
public void AddProduct()
{
    formModel.Items.Add(new FormProduct()
    {
        Id = AvailableProducts.FirstOrDefault().Id,
        Product = AvailableProducts.FirstOrDefault(),
        Quantity = 1,
    });

    // Notify EditContext of the change
    FormEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(() => formModel.Items));
}
```

```
public void RemoveProduct(
    FormProduct formProduct)
{
    formModel.Items.Remove(formProduct);

    // Notify EditContext of the change
    FormEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(() => formModel.Items));
}
```